# How to reset the menu items to defaults

Tags: menu, admin

On a site where an old admin has moved all the menu items around, is there a simple way to reset the menu items to the defaults like you'd see if you installed CiviCRM fresh?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside the CiviCRM root directory is a "sql" folder, and inside that is "civicrm_navigation.mysql".  Copy it to "civicrm_navigation_restore.sql" and edit the copy to remove all of the SQL commands EXCEPT this one:
`SELECT @domainID := id FROM civicrm_domain where name = 'Default Domain Name';`

and any that start with `INSERT INTO civicrm_navigation`.

Change the `SELECT @domainID` line to read:
`SET @domainID = 1;` (assuming this isn't multi-site).

Then run (after first backing up your database!)
`DELETE FROM civicrm_navigation`.

Finally, run `mysql -u myusername -pmypassword databasename < civicrm_navigation_restore.mysql`.

Comment: Is this still the best approach to getting old sites to have the latest arrangement. Tired of having to look in multiple places in the Admin menu for Extensions ;-)